# How to convert VectorAssembler output which is Vector type to Array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

The vectorAssembler function in spark gives a vector[double] type as output, but i need to convert that to array[double].
I know that there is an inbuild `Vector_to_array` function provided but i am not getting how to convert the column to array
some of the elements are sparse array as well.

```
var assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("Pclass",
  "Age",
  "Fare",
  "Gender",
  "Boarded"
)).setOutputCol("features")
var transformedDF =  assembler.setHandleInvalid("skip").transform(updatedDF)
```

this is the code and i need to convert the features column from vector to array type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alias for Vector depending on ml or mllib library, to not get confused with Scala's Vector

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector => MLVector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector => MLlibVector
```

Then create a UDF

```
// 1. function to map to Array[Double]
val vec2Array: Any => Array[Double] = {
  vector => vector match {
    case vec: MLVector => vec.toArray
    case vec: MLlibVector => vec.toArray
  }
}
// 2. User Defined Function (UDF)
val vec2ArrayUDF = udf(vec2Array)
// 3. apply UDF on "features" column
val df_vec2Array = transformedDF.withColumn("features_array",vec2ArrayUDF(col("features")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this really helped, can u tell me where can i learn udf from, i am not really understanding what is happening in the bgrd.
Thanks

Comment: Sure, udf are really just as this 3 steps: 1. define a Scala function, 2. put it inside udf() and 3. apply it on a DF. For a start this introduction is good https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs.html, for more in depth information I can recommend „Spark: The Definitive Guide“ Ch.6 Working with different Types of Data, User-Defined Functions